# How to revert changes by svnsync on mirror

Tags: svn, svnsync

I have a Mirror and Master, recently the sync from master stopped because of lock issue.
After using svn propset --revprop i managed to restart the sync but after few revision sync, got an error message ,svnsync cant find a file at mirror.
Real Problem is at 20th revision structure of both repositories are different

"http://Mirror/Sets/Hw/trunk/Emu/token"

"http://Master/Sets/Hw/trunk/token"

However comments for all revision which has been synched is same.

Currently master is at 100th revision and mirror cant move from 20th revision ,because of structural difference and svnsync not able to replicate the revision due to it.
Please suggest is there any provision to undo svnsync on mirror and restart svnsync or if there is any better option?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really an answer for fixing mirror, but you always have an option to recreate mirror by running svnsync on a new clean repository. May take less human time...

Comment: Have you committed on the mirror ? Otherwise it should run without any problem?